# react-router modal solution makes unnecessary re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using this official react-router Modal-Gallery example:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery

but instead of using the thumbnail colors, I'm fetching images.

- problem is that whenever I open or close the modal, the Gallery component re-renders(unnecessarily), and the images are re-fetched again.

how do I prevent that?

Comment: Keep in mind that a re-render can only be triggered if a component's state has changed. The state can change from a props change, or from a direct setState change. Maybe the reason of your problem is that you use state to handle the visible/hidden status of modal. Each time you open or close the modal, there is a state mutation which will trigger a re-render. Hope it help! Unless, please provide some snippet for better support!

Comment: @CamSong thanks, the modal is conditionally rendered by URL path, not by changing a state.
I fixed the images re-fetching problem, I was declaring functional components inside the main functional component, moved them out I the problem was fixed.
* react is re-rendering a lot of unrelated components, it seems normal, but I don't understand it.